# What is the best time to implement Multiplayer system?

Tags: multiplayer

I have been starting a new online multiplayer game project this week and as the title says - Is it better to implement the Multiplayer feature right away, or is it ok to implement it when the game already has some other stuff, like maps and physics?

Comment: Right away. You don't even want to think about the complexity of implementing it later on, and then having to reimplement all your logic around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you implement the network will inform everything else you do in the game. Implementing networking later is always a bad idea.

Here's an example of a released game with local coop and what happened when they tried to implement networked coop later:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/408410/discussions/0/1697176044371195631/

> Unfortunately, despite our multiple attempts and best intentions, we
>   have not delivered the online version of the co-op game mode. The main
>   problem with the game is that it’s heavily physics based and it
>   affects gameplay, thus we would have to make the physics 100%
>   predictable or to completely rework the whole framework for it to be
>   able to send physics information in multiplayer. Unfortunately, this
>   would require 6-9 months of work for 2-3 programmers and so we decided
>   that we won't be able to pull it off.